# jar runs on Windows but doesn't on Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-native-interface, compatibility

I'm using Maven to generate a runnable jar file of my project with all dependencies (copied in a separated folder).

http://pastebin.com/NfhiVZhM (link to pom.xml to avoid copy giant xml here)

I'm running mvn package on a Windows 10 machine with jdk 1.8. After mvn run, if I open cmd and run java `-jar instagramBot.jar` everything works normally.

The folder where Maven generates the result (target) is synchronized by Dropbox with an Ubuntu machine with oracle-jdk-1.8.

But if open a shell on Ubuntu and go run the same command the result is:

> rafa@Bangkok:~/svn/instagramBot/target$ java -jar instagramBot.jar
>   Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/tomatechines/instagramapi/services/exception/InstagramException

After this is printed the JVM stacktrace and the program crashes.

I already triple checked that the jar containing `com/tomatechines/instagramapi/services/exception/InstagramException`is present in the classpath and also present in the libraries folder in the Ubuntu machine. But the error keeps happening.

I also checked for any kind of special character that may appear in the jars names but I dind't find nothing.

The stack trace hasn't any futher explanation to the error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again

Does anyone have any idea what might be or what else should I check to identify the problem?

**==============UPDATE============**

All libraries I use are jars. No DLLs or OS specific files.

I tried to export a runnable jar file by Eclipse and packing all the libraries in a single jar (58MB), it works normally on Ubuntu... I don't want to use this aproach because my code is going to change a lot and the libraries I use don't, but if I pack everything in a single jar, everytime I fix a small bug, I will need to re-synchronize 58MB, despite the fact Eclipse process to exporting jar is pretty not convenient.

Comment: JNI is Java Native Interface, which is how Java talks to native libraries (libs written specifically for the OS, for example in C or C++). Does the program you're trying to run require a native library? Do you have the relevant lib for Linux in the right place? (Note: Windows DLLs do not work on Linux, you'll need a Linux-specific version of the library).

Comment: NO! All libraries I use are jars. Now I tried to export a runnable jar file by eclipse and packing all the libraries in a single jar (58MB) it works normally on ubuntu...

Comment: The error says check your installation. It may be referring to the jvm itself

Comment: Is it a multi module project? What command do you use with maven? Can you show the output of maven?

Comment: @asettouf, isnt multi module, the command i use is just mvn package (the pom.xml you can check at the link). the mvn output you can check http://pastebin.com/gW4tQuX6 but there is nothing special

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here

```
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent
```

You might want to declare in your pom the source encoding as utf8, see [this link](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning)

```
<properties>
    ...
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    ...
</properties>
```

Comment: Adding this information in pom stops the warning but doesn't solve my problem, I keep getting the error and now I get on Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: Actually it wasn't your suggestion that made the project stop working on windows... was another "fix" maven suggested to me and i didn't checked... now the problem is solved. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem and actually I couldn't understand why it solved but i'm to tired to try understand...

if I run the mvn package with the pom on http://pastebin.com/NfhiVZhM I get two warnings

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for InstagramBot:InstagramBot:jar:2.0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 26, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

//lot of info outputs//

```
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

And I get a runnable jar file that works fine on Windows.
The manifest of this jar looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: rafael
Class-Path: dependency/utils-1.4.3.jar dependency/commons-io-2.5.jar d
 ependency/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar dependency/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.22.jar de
 pendency/log4j-1.2.17.jar dependency/hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar d
 ependency/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar dependency/hibernate-jpa-2.1-
 api-1.0.0.Final.jar dependency/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar dependency/ant
```

as the first warning is too big, I solved it just after posting on pastebin, by just addig the following line in my maven-jar-plugin (the line addressed on warning)

```
<version>3.0.0</version>
```

simple doing this the manifest created by maven changes to:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: rafael
Class-Path: dependency/com/tomatechines/utils/1.4.3/utils-1.4.3.jar de
 pendency/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar dependency/org/
 slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar dependency/org/slf4j/slf4
 j-log4j12/1.7.22/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.22.jar dependency/log4j/log4j/1.2.
 17/log4j-1.2.17.jar dependency/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.1.0.Fin
```

it tries to look for a repository structure for the libs in my project, BUT, the copy dependencies plugin just create a single folder (dependency) and put all jars inside. So the manifest looks for a folder structure that never existed and this jar doens't work on windows nor ubuntu.

The solution was to remove the `<version>` and add the

`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`

as suggested by @asettouf. Now I've back the big warning but the jar works fine on both plataform... And i really dont care about that warning while it is working